# Flutter file_picker returns 'null' on Android API 34

Tags: android, flutter, filepicker

i have built a flutter social media app and use the plugin "file_picker" to pick an image from the gallery as the profile image:

```
FilePickerResult? result =
  await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.media,
  allowMultiple: false,
);
```

But when i try to pick an image from my android phone (API level 33) or android emulator (API level 34), the file_picker just returns 'null' and 'User cancelled the picker request'.

```
print(result);
```

Output:

```
I/FilePickerDelegate( 1841): User cancelled the picker request
I/flutter ( 1841): null
```

Any idea what is going on here?

If i create an emulator with API level 31 or below, everything works as expected and i can pick images from all sorts of folders.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the launchaMode your using in AndroidManifest.xml class?

Answer (score 0):

*You should give permission for access storage from gallery.

> remove allowMultiple: false

and update like this,

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);
```

Comment: You cannot ask for help with one line question. This is the sign of laziness. That to me is the title. Then should follow a detailed explanation of what you are doing, what you want to achieve and what is happening. You can include where necessary snippets of your codes.